# Why does PassportJS keep redirecting me to failureRedirect?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to use PassportJS to protect certain routes of a web application. I'm ussing Passport, ExpressJS, and MongoDB. I find that after an apparently successful authentication, every attempt to access one of these protected routes gets redirected to `/login` again, as if the login had failed.

I've tried making a new project to try and test just this part, and I'm getting the same behaviour: there is an `/authenticated` route, that needs the user to be logged in, and an `/unauthenticated` one that doesn't. After successfully logging in through the `/login` POST route, the user should be redirected to `/authenticated`; if the logging was unsuccessful, they'd be redirected back to `/login`.

However, after correctly being redirected to `/authenticated`, the user is redirected back to `/login`!

[image: screenshoot showing the redirects]

What can I possibly be doing wrong here? The user has been successfully logged in, why are they being redirected back to `failureRedirect`?

All the pertinent code is in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/jkurei/passport-test). I'll include next the server.js file and the login form:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
  <label for=login_name>username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username"><br/>
  <label for=password>password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password"><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

This is the Express configuration:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3004));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // Permissive CORS header
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Here is the Passport setup:

```
function verify (username, password, done) {

  db.collection("users").findOne({ username: username })
  .then(
    doc => {
      if (!doc) {
        console.log(`User ${username} doesn't exist`);
        done(null, false, { message: "User doesn't exist" });
      }
      if (doc.password != password) {
        console.log(`${password} is the wrong password`);
        done(null, false, { message: "Wrong password" });
      }
      else { 
        console.log("AOK"); 
        done(null, doc); 
      }
    }, 
    reason => done(reason)
  );
}

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(verify));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log("Serialize here, got " + JSON.stringify(user));
  done(null, user._id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  db.collection("users").findOne({ _id: id })
  .then(
    doc => done(null, doc),
    reason => done(reason)
  );
});
```

And these are my routes:

```
app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile("./login.html", "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(data);
})});

app.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
}), (req, res) => { res.redirect("/authenticated")}); 

var ensureLoggedIn = require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn("/login");
app.get("/authenticated", ensureLoggedIn, (req, res) => res.send("o hai"));
app.get("/unauthenticated", (req, res) => res.send("o hai"));

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
  console.log('Server started: http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '/');
});
```

Also, these are the versions of each library I'm using:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.1",
    "connect-ensure-login": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "express-session": "^1.13.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.1.19",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7"
  },
```

**PD:** I'm only using clear-text passwords for this small test, and nowhere near a production DB.

Comment: Does it work if you convert `id` to an `ObjectId` in `deserializeUser`? `db.collection("users").findOne({ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(id) })`

Comment: You are right. I never needed to do that, and I actually have other calls to `findOne` working perfectly without that. I didn't notice `deserializeUser` wasn't working. If you want, do a full answer that I can accept. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using Mongoose, perhaps? Mongoose will cast strings to ObjectId automatically, but your query in `deserializeUser()` uses MongoDB directly.

Comment: No mongoose, but i just checked and all the other ids are string that my application composes before calling mongo's create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deserializeUser()` gets passed the `id` as a string, but for direct MongoDB queries against `_id` you need to convert it to an `ObjectId` first:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  db.collection("users").findOne({ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(id) })
  .then(
    doc => done(null, doc),
    reason => done(reason)
  );
});
```